# Rails 4 seeds.rb updating associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, seeding

I am generating numerous nested objects in my seeds.rb file and have run in to a problem. All of the objects are created properly, except the attributes that are tied to a parent object. In the following file:

**seeds.rb**

```
accounts.each do |i|
    80.times do |j|
        type = types.sample
            case (type)
                ...
            end
        t = AcctTransaction.new
            t.account_id = i.id
            t.transaction_type_id = type
            t.description = description
            t.amount = amount
            # keep transaction in chronological order unless it's the first one
            unless AcctTransaction.exists?(account_id: t.account_id)
                t.date = rand(i.date_opened..Time.now)
            else
                t.date = rand(AcctTransaction.where(account_id: t.account_id).last.date..Time.now)
            end
            t.adjusted_bal = i.balance + t.amount
        i.update_attribute :balance, t.adjusted_bal
        t.save
        account_transactions << t
    end
end
```

Rake db:seed runs without error, and generates the 80 transactions per account (about 12000 total transactions). **The only problem is** the values generated for *adjusted_bal* (of the AcctTransactions model) and the updated value of the *balance* (the Accounts model) are incorrect. They simply need to reflect the calculation of **present balance + transaction amount**.

Is there something wrong with my calculation or the loop itself, or am I using the wrong method(s) to assign these calculated values to their respective models? I've tried this 100 different ways with no luck. Please help.

It's Rails 4.1.8 / Ruby 2.1.5. Thank you.

**EDIT**

> **To clarify..**
>
> This part of the seed file should do the following:
>
> 1. For each account (already assigned to "accounts variable" and iterated with "i"), generate 80 unique transactions
> 2. Add the amount of the transaction to the account's present balance
> 3. Store that value as "adjusted_bal" in the AcctTransactions table, and also use this value to update the "balance" in the Accounts table
> 4. The loop runs 80 times and each time, "balance" should be different - having been modified by the previous iteration.
>
> **Example**
>
> 1st iteration:
>
> - *original* account balance is 100 (for example).
> - transaction amount (random) is -50.
> - (-50) + 100 = 50. This is stored in the transaction as adjusted_bal
> - Also, the account model's balance column is changed to "50", as this is the account's new balance.
>
> 2nd iteration:
>
> - Now the account balance is 50 (having been updated by the last transaction loop iteration)
> - transaction amount (random) is 25.
> - 25 + 50 = 75. This is stored in the transaction as adjusted_bal
> - Also, the account model's balance column is changed to "75" also, as this is the account's new balance.
>
> (Do this 80 times)
>
> Hope that makes it more clear. Thanks

**EDIT**
**Screen clip of (incorrect) result...**
[image: Screen clip of (incorrect) result]

As you can see from this screen clip (zoom in), the **account balance** in the heading is $1073.62 US. And in each transaction, the *balance* column (which is *adjusted_bal* from the acct_transaction model) is EXACTLY the **amount** subtracted from $1073.62 - Meaning that the account balance is never changed.

Comment: The thing is that you are updating that i.balance 80 times, which one is correct? or is it like the sum of all 80 + original amount ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes, the balance for the account ( i ) is updated 80 times, _resulting_ in all 80 + original amount. I do this because the balance changes with each transaction, and I need to store a "running balance" (the change that is caused by the transaction), in the "adjusted_bal" column of the acct_transaction. This way when I view the transactions list, it can display the balance at that exact point in time (i.e. online banking transaction history). I'm updating the post so that is more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, seems fine with me, but allow me to clean it up for you a bit, it should also work faster cause it does less queries, it might help you figure out where the problem is.. maybe lol

```
accounts.each do |account|
  80.times do    # no need for iterator
    type = types.sample
    case (type)
      # ...
    end

    # this will save and insert the new transaction in the collection
    # at the same time
    # will save you the second query that updates the relation
    account_transactions.create do |transaction|
      transaction.account_id = account.id
      transaction.transaction_type_id = type
      transaction.description = description
      transaction.amount = amount
      transaction.adjusted_bal = account.balance + transaction.amount

      # doing a first_or_initialize, will save you one query
      # in loops where the record actually exist
      transaction.date =
        (t = AcctTransaction.where(account_id: t.account_id).first_or_initalize).persisted? ?
        rand(account.date_opened..Time.now) :
        rand(t.date..Time.now)
    end 
  end
  # save only once after the 80 loops, before moving to the next account
  # could save you up to 80 queries in each loop 
  account.save
end
```

Comment: This was a lot faster. However, it still yields the same results. The adjusted_bal isn't correct when listing the transactions. I'll add a screen clip to the post to illustrate. Also, I reverted back to the "unless" way of generating dates for the transaction. Got undefined method for your way, although it looks much cleaner. I'm voting this up because it is much prettier code than mine. Please see the screen clip I add to see what happened. Thanks!

Comment: BTW Please disregard the "Transaction ID" column in the screen shot. It is arbitrarily generated to reflect some "vendor-assigned" stamp. Thanks

Comment: **Found another clue.** If you look at the above screen clip (zoom in), notice the account balance in the heading ($1073.62 US). Then, if you look at the balance in the table (which is `adjusted_bal` for the transaction), It is _exactly_ the `amount` subtracted from 1073.62! This means that the amount is subtracted from the original balance, which never changes.

Comment: so the total balance above should be `$1347.86` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I ran the seed again with puts account.balance to console and it indeed stays the same after each generated acct_transaction. I know I could just echo the adjusted bal ($1347.86) but that doesn't fix the problem of model not updating in the db.

Comment: well from what i could say, the number above is the 2nd transaction value, so i think for some reason the last transaction in the loop doesn't save it's value somehow, does that sound like something that could be happening?

Comment: Thanks but that's actually $1013.62 (after a $60 transaction). Sorry for the tiny image. So the balance remains the same each time. I don't know if maybe Rails is prohibiting seeds file from performing update action? But if that were the case I'd think it would raise exception.

Comment: yea i can see the number, but if you add that `60` it will become `1073.62`

Comment: Correct, but by the same token if you calculate any of the transaction amounts (subtract the negative amounts or add the unsigned amounts), it always equals 1073.62. For instance, after that $60 transaction, the balance column shows $1013.62. The next transaction after that is a $274.24 deposit. If the balance was correct, this transaction would yield a value of $1287.86 (the sum of 1013.62 and 274.24). Instead, the deposit amount is added to $1073.62, resulting with a value of $1347.86 in the balance column.

Comment: you should debug and put some break points, and see why the values aren't being updated.

Comment: well this is an idea i just thought, maybe the saving is failing due to some validation error or something like that, replace `create` with `create!` and `save` with `save!`

Comment: Somehow, that does the trick! Also, I had to change the **update** method to this syntax: `account.update(balance: transaction.adjusted_bal)`. Not sure why that matters, but other variations of update syntax failed. I'm marking your above answer as correct, but maybe you could edit to show the "bang" in your last comment and the update syntax I use here. THANK YOU so much for all your help!!